# What approach is efficient to read large file and display data in html page

Tags: asp.net, file-io

I have a web server which will read large xml files (several megs) containing data to display. 
The server could be reading several files at the same time (different page requests) so I am looking for the most optimized way for doing this without taxing the CPU too much. The html page should display data in the form of grid with pagesize = 20 . There will be client side paging to show data for each page. I have been thinking of one of the following approaches:

1. Each ajax request should return only 20 records and every request should open the file , read data and send back only required data to the browser. The concern is cost of File I/O.
2. On the first ajax request , server should read the whole file and send the whole data back to the browser.

The website will be developed in asp.net with session saved out of proc. Please suggest the best approach to consume data from a file efficiently.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: We do something similar to this involving street lookup: I would go option 1, with an intelligent request. For example, utilize an ajax autocompleteextender to send a request to your web service. That way it wont need to send the entire file back, but perhaps a snippit from it.

Comment: Will each user be looking at a separate xml file, or will they be looking at the same xml file?

Comment: Each user will be looking for a separate xml file.